# No data being displayed after a space or '

Tags: php, html

I am sure this is somewhere, but I have been looking for hours and can not find an answer that deals with my specific problem.  I am trying to create a datalist.  My problem is that when I recall the information from the database I only get part of the information.  Any data after a space is removed.

One of the property names is: Wright's Mill

Here is the original code:

```
    $resultSet1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT propname FROM properties");
```

```
                <p><input list="propname" name="propertyname">
                        <datalist id="propname">
                            <option value="All">
                            <?php
                                while($rows =$resultSet1->fetch_assoc()){
                                    $propname = $rows['propname'];
                                    echo "<option value= $propname >";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </datalist></p>
```

Using this code I get... Wright's

I have tried putting $propname in quotes'$propname' like so:

```
                <p><input list="propname" name="propertyname">
                        <datalist id="propname">
                            <option value="All">
                            <?php
                                while($rows =$resultSet1->fetch_assoc()){
                                    $propname = $rows['propname'];
                                    echo "<option value= '$propname' >";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </datalist></p>
```

This only gives me... Wright

if someone could please point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

EDIT:

I have been able to get the datalist to work properly

```
            <p><input list="properties" name="propertyname">
                    <datalist id="properties">
                    <option>All</option>
                    <?php
                        while($rows =$resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
                            $propname = $rows['propname'];
                            $value = htmlspecialchars($propname, ENT_QUOTES);
                            echo "<option value='$value'></option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </datalist</p>
```

I had commented that it was not working with the htmlspecialchars(), but that was because I had left out the ENT_QUOTES

Comment: The given answer is good, but you may also want to check out [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), as it will resolve the issue you found in the second case

Comment: I tried that, but it only gives me Wright

Comment: You should update your question to include that attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<option>` tag is usually written with an open and a closing tag. If the display value and the value are the same, you can omit the `value` attribute:

```
$value = htmlspecialchars($propname);
echo "<option>$value</option>"
```

Edit: As noted by Patrick Q, if you wanted to pass `$propname` to the `value` attribute in `<option>` you would want to escape it first to handle a case where your input has a `'`, which would prematurely close the `value` tag:

```
$value = htmlspecialchars($propname);
echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>"
```

Comment: it does work for the drop down list, but creates a problem with my "SELECT propname FROM properties WHERE propname = '$propname'");

Comment: I get this error...  Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Mill''

Comment: @Philip  That's a separate question, the answer to which is likely "use prepared statements with bound parameters instead of directly injecting variables into a query"